# Setting content offset of a UITableView not working when it's scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

Here's my code

```
// 1
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
  scrollTableView()
}

// 2
@IBAction func buttonPressed() {
  scrollTableView()
}

// 3
func scrollTableView() {
  tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
  // tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), animated:true) // does not work either
}
```

Even **method 1** (who calls method 3) being called, the Table View continues its natural scrolling decelerating until it stops. It does not position itself where I want.

When the Table View is not scrolling and I call **method 2** by pressing a button it does get its content offset set and it positions where it should.

How can I get it to work by being called in the **method 1**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i got you right the following should work:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  scrollTableView()
}
```

Comment: I wanna use scrollViewDidEndDragging because I want the table view to scroll as soon as the user lifts his finger

Comment: i am not really sure what you are trying to achieve :) can you maybe explain a little more in detail?

Comment: I want the table view to scroll to the top as soon as the user lifts his finger after scrolling

Comment: and you want it to stay at the top and cancel the scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

You should also implement `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`

with `scrollViewDidEndDragging: willDecelerate:`

`scrollViewDidEndDragging: willDecelerate:` is called always

and

`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is called when table decelerate and decelerating is ended.

Comment: I wanna use scrollViewDidEndDragging because I want the table view to scroll as soon as the user lifts his finger

Comment: // called on finger up if the user dragged. decelerate is true if it will continue moving afterwards
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;

Comment: implement
func stopScroll ( )
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    offset.x -= 1.0;
    offset.y -= 1.0;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
    offset.x += 1.0;
    offset.y += 1.0;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
}
and call it in scrollViewDidEndDragging: willDecelerate: method

Comment: and after that call scrollTableView()

Comment: that function stopScroll() will have the same behavior: it will not work if table view is scrolling

Comment: implement the same in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating delegate also

Comment: then it will be too late, I don't want it even to start decelerating